# How to call a constructor for a class inside another class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have a class `first` in which I want to have another element that its type is another class. Something like this:

```
class first{

private:

    second secondAvl;
public:

    first():second(-1){}  // i get erroe here
} 

class second: public Tree{

private:

public:
 second(int key) :Tree(NULL,key1){} // here it worked to call contructor for tree
}
```

My problem is that when I try to call the constructor for second in class first constructor I get this error:

> no matching function for call to 'second::second()'

Any help what I am doing wrong? Because I did the same thing when I called the constructor for tree in the second class and that worked fine.

Comment: You need to name the member, not the member's type. `first() : secondAvl(-1) {}` Consider what would happen if you have two `second` members. You only name the type when you call a base type's constructor. And remember that `second` must be declared before being used in `first`.

Comment: `first():second(-1){}` This says: "When default-constructing a `first`, initialize my member named `second` by calling its constructor with a value of `-1`."  You don't have a member named `second`, so this fails.

Comment: dublicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41534186/c-calling-another-class-constructor]

Comment: The code provided could not trigger the error reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in the order you define the classes, class `second` is not known at the time it is used in `first`. You should actually get other error messages.
Second, in the initializer list, you need to address the variable to initialize by its name (i.e. `: secondAvl(-1)`), not by its type `: second(-1)`.

See the following working example:

```
class second {

private:

public:
    second(int key) {} // here it worked to call contructor for tree
};


class first{

private:

    second secondAvl;
public:

    first():secondAvl(-1){}  // i get erroe here
};
```

Answer (score -1):

do instead:

```
...

private:

    second secondAvl;
public:

    first() : secondAvl(-1)
    { }  
}
```

or uniform initialization using {}

```
...

private:

    second secondAvl;
public:

    first() : secondAvl{-1}
    { }  
}
```